# WPF TranslateTransform is ScaleTransforming

Tags: wpf, transform, pathgeometry, scatterview

In the following code part is Part class's object which is inherited from **ScatterViewItem** class (Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls). part.Content is Path geometry:

```
GeometryGroup gGroup = new GeometryGroup
{
    FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero
};
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Part> kv in Layers)
{
    geom = part.ShadowPath.RenderedGeometry.Clone();
    geom.Transform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
    gGroup.Children.Add(geom);
}
```

When I comment `geom.Transform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);` line, it shows with right scale but when I uncomment it, although  I am not changing anything, it scales paths:
[image]

I want to know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you check the value of `geom.Transform` before you assigned a new value?

Comment: @Clemens, yes it was one MatrixTranslate was there. I just got it and modified OffsetX and OffsetY properties. I can mark as a right answer if you write it. #Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Clemens was right about initial transformation values: there was matrixTransform with automatically calculated values by WPF. When I assigned new transformation values, it totally removed old values. I just picked that matrix and updated some values and it worked fine.